# How do you know which table has returned the data

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which joins 2 tables and checks if the `username` exists in either `users` Table or `registered` Table. This works OK, how do I modify this query to show which `table` returns the data? Note: I do not want to do it in PHP.

```
   SELECT
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?) AS found_username,
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM registered WHERE nameFirst = ?) AS found_name
```

Comment: You've got two values - it's simpler to check those in your PHP than to somehow change the query to automagically encode which of the two tables the entry was found in.

Comment: `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ...) THEN 'source table identifier' END AS fieldname`.

Comment: @Akina I don't understand can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Then please define what form of output is actually useful to you.   Unless this value is being directly inserted back into another table via a stored procedure I would still suggest that it's simpler to have the recipient of this query's output parse the two columns to determine the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not join 2 tables.
It queries separately the 2 tables and returns 2 columns with values `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.
You can do what you want by using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?) THEN 'from users'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM registered WHERE nameFirst = ?) THEN 'from registered'
    ELSE 'not found'
  END
```

If there is a case that both tables may contain the name then change to this:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN t.found_username AND t.found_name THEN 'both'
    WHEN t.found_username THEN 'from users'
    WHEN t.found_name THEN 'from registered'
    ELSE 'not found'
  END
FROM (
   SELECT
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?) AS found_username,
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM registered WHERE nameFirst = ?) AS found_name
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`:

```sql
SELECT username AS found_username, 'users' AS `table` FROM users WHERE username = ?
UNION
SELECT nameFirst AS found_username, 'registered' AS `table` FROM registered WHERE nameFirst = ?
```